# Styling escape character in Sublime Text

Tags: ruby, regex, sublimetext2, sublimetext, color-scheme

I want to style escape character and only escape character differently using custom color scheme (I intend to make it faded to make regexp more readable).

Is it possible to do this? Preferably it would work in general, but something limited to Ruby also would be highly useful.

Comment: Do you mean the actual escape character `\ ` ?

Comment: Yes, for example ```/\(([^()]*)\)/``` would be more readable with escape character displayed in a different style (in SO style - between black and gray).

Answer (score 0):

It sure is possible!

```
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Escape character</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>constant.character.escape</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#F38630</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Actually this is the scope for the escape character along with the escaped character.

[image]

[image]

Remember you may always find the corresponding scope by moving the caret to the characters and pressing:

`{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+shift+p"], "command": "show_scope_name" }`

(You will see the scope key in the status bar).

Comment: "escape character along with the escaped character" - that is not what I want. I intend to make escape character less visible than other parts of regexp, including escaped character.

Comment: @MateuszKonieczny I'm afraid that's not possible without writing custom scope definitions. But it sure is possible with them